# Wordpress blocks: async REST calls in registerBlockType edit function

Tags: javascript, wordpress, rest, asynchronous, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm writing a WordPress plugin that creates a block, the block needs to pull data using a custom REST endpoint that returns, in the example below, a simple string. I'd like to include this string in the return from edit() and save() in my registerBlockType config but. I'm using fetch() to call the REST endpoint but this, obviously, is async. Any thoughts on the best way to do this appreciated, thanks:

```
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks 

registerBlockType( 'daisy-views/da-test', {
    title:      'Daisy Test: Test Block',
    icon:       'format-gallery',
    category:   'common',
    attributes: {
        gid: {
            default: 2,
            type:   'integer'
        },
    },

    edit( props ) {

        const restEP = daRestUrl + 'test'

        fetch( restEP, {
            body: JSON.stringify( {p: 'test param'}),  // test parameters
            cache: 'no-cache',
            method: 'POST',
            redirect: 'follow', 
            referrer: 'no-referrer', 
            headers : {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
                'X-WP-Nonce' : wpApiSettings.nonce,
            }
        })
            .then( response => {
                response.json()
                    .then( data => {
                        var returnValue = data.data                     // REST test, returns a string
                        console.log( 'Fetch returns: ', returnValue )
                    })
            })

        return <div>
            test block edit
                {/* return value from fetch here */}
            </div>
    },
    save( props ) {

        return <div>
            Test Block
            {/* return value from fetch here */}
            </div>
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

My best solution, to date, is to add a code attribute and have the fetch call fill that attribute with HTML. if fetch is called directly in the edit function there needs to be a check to prevent it from being called in an endless loop when it updates the attribute.